# Avoid inverse of matrix

Tags: c, matlab, matrix-multiplication

I want to avoid computing the inverse of a matrix. I am writing code in C, so I cannot use MATLAB commands for this. I want to perfrom the following calculation:

```
v = bk/G;
```

`bk` is a 2 × 1 matrix and `G` is a 2 × 2 matrix, `v` is a float variable.

I am currently doing this:

```
V = G^-1 * bk;
```

This way, I have to use the division operator for finding `G^-1`. I want to avoid using divisions.

Comment: Avoid inverse or division? And why? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `c`?

Comment: @Daniel Because OP is programming in C it seems.

Comment: @Daniel, why is it tagged matlab??:)

Comment: `v = G^-1 * bk` produces a vector not a scalar...

Comment: Can you add a few more details? For example, if `G` is an orthogonal matrix, then `G⁻¹ = G'`, what libraries do you have available in C, etc.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis. While that may be relevant in the general case, and I would normally recommend using LAPACK, `G` is `2x2`. That's pretty much all you need here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yup, the 2×2 requirement was edited in after I started writing that comment, so please ignore it :)

Comment: But if the matrix is 2×2, why avoid comptuing its inverse?

Comment: Think of it as a different kind of elaboration from the one you were looking for :)

Comment: @LuisMendo. I think the OP is just equating the slash operator in MATLAB with the general concept of matrix inversion. It looks like a case of lack of linear algebra knowledge rather a deficiency in programming.

Comment: @MadPhysicist That makes sense, yes

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are trying not so much avoid inverting a matrix as to find a different way to do it. Since `G` is a `2x2` matrix, you lucked out as it is trivial to compute the [inverse of a 2x2 matrix](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm).

```
G = [a b; c d]
G^-1 = (1/det(G)) * [d -b; -c a]
```

or in C:

```
double a, b, c, d;
double *G = {a, c, b, d}; // I used matlab internal (column-wise) order for the matrix here
double det = a * d - b * c;
if(det == 0.0) { /* Throw up your hands and lament */ }
double Ginv = {d / det, -c / det, -b / det, a / det};
```

where `det(G)` is the determinant: `ad - bc`. You can use the determinant to test if the matrix is invertible in the first place. If `det(G) == 0`, one over the determinant is undefined and the matrix is non-invertible.

Comment: Note that `det(G)==0` detects only the worst problems; try `inv( [0 1; eps 1]  )` or so

Comment: Sure, you can do something like `abs(det(G)) < some_small_but_not_too_small_number_depending_on_the_expected_magnitude_of_the_values_in_G`. In fact, I probably would. Think of this answer as more of an intro to the subject for the OP :)

Comment: A better intro would apparently be a linear algebra course; it's actually not really a programmatic problem.

Comment: I agree. Note the link I posted is to an introductory math site. Maybe this will motivate the OP to do just that.

Comment: @Mad Physicist ,Actually I want to avoid inverse of this matrix cause I am trying to find out minimum delta_I(or error) by using Newton-Raphson method.I am using this NR method which is very iterative and in that I am doing division operation which is very costly .So I want to avoid this by any mathematical way .

Comment: Not to be *that* guy, but are there only *slightly* iterative methods? Basically, if you compute by hand the elements of `Ginv*v` for a vector `v`, you can try playing around with the formulae (I mean basic algebra). If that doesn't help, nothing will, as `Ginv*v` is just what it is (so the best you can do is try to avoid some possible loss-of-precision problems).

Comment: The code above has exactly four divisions in it. You can reduce it to one if you store `1.0/det` and multiply by it. For Newton Raphson, you should not have enough iterations for it to make a difference.